# Python - print in an if,elif, else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I want this code to NOT print "You guessed.." and "You have.." if the "if" statement is false, but make it print if the "elif" and "else" statement is true.

Is there an easy way to do this, without typing it into the "elif" and "else" statement?

```
def input_guess(guess):

    ....

    print 'You guessed: ', guess_num,'.',
    print 'You have', remainding_guess_times, 'guesses left.',

    if guess_num == real_num:
        print 'Congratulations, blablabla!'
        new_game()
    elif guess_num > real_num:
        print 'blablabla'
    else:
        print 'blablabla'

    ...
```

Comment: can you ask your question again - I am not sure I understand what you mean ...

Comment: this: `if guess_num == guess_num:` always evaluates to `True`. Make self-containing example, if you want answer to your problem. And explain what you want to know...

Comment: @m.wasowski the same also applies to the `>` part.

Comment: As written, you can get rid of the "elif" statement and put your prints in the else.  If you had other logic, you could move the prints into a function and call that function from both the if and elif.

Comment: I think you want to place the “You guessed…” and “You have … guesses left” parts *after* your checks but it is hard to say without knowing how your code is supposed to be used.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks, that was the answer i was looking for.
Sorry for bad explanation, very new to programming, and i didn't really know how to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def input_guess(guess):

    ....

    if guess_num == real_num:
        print 'Congratulations, blablabla!'
        new_game()
    else:
        print 'You guessed: ', guess_num,'.',
        print 'You have', remainding_guess_times, 'guesses left.',

        if guess_num > real_num:
            print 'blablabla'
        else:
            print 'blablabla'
```